# schedule an email using php and mysql without opening/accessing the website/webpage

Tags: php

how can i run the code below with out opening the website/domain. i have tried to use cron jobs but still i need to open the website and refresh the page.

```
<?php

    $currentDate = date("d m Y");
    $setDate = date("04 08 Y");

    if ($setDate == $currentDate) {
        $to = "somebody@example.com";
        $subject = "My subject";
        $txt = "Hello world!";
        $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

        mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
        echo "email notification sent";
     }else{
        echo "email not sent";
    }
?>
```

Comment: google `cronjob`

Comment: If this is a cron job, why would you need to open a page on the website

Comment: Where else have you tried to run it? Did you run it in a terminal by calling it directly? What happened when you tried to run the code, did you get any errors, any output at all?

Comment: Cron job you set up wasn't running then.

Comment: it will run the specific page.php but doesn't send an email with out me manually refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

To run it from cron, try adding the following code to the top of the file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: im using the cronjob from cpanel                                                      /opt/php55/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: So, in the file, you would use this: #!/opt/php55/bin/php

Comment: or crontab -e from terminal and just add the command in to run it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i am on shared hosting and running the code once per minute is not allowed. so i change it to */15 * * * *.

not allowed on hostgator shared hosting

```
*/1 *   *   *   */opt/php55/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

working command

```
*/15    *   *   *   */opt/php55/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

[Time intervals for hostgator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmJNN.png)